# How can I filter Node.js stdout and stderr messages?

Tags: node.js, promise, stdout, stack-overflow, stderr

Whenever an async function overflows, there are two messages being output in the console via `stdout` and `stderr`: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, `Exception in PromiseRejectCallback:`.

I am making a library which handles the overflow and outputs the error, but the problem is that I don't think there is an API for turning those messages off. The only relevant things I found were [this node.js code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/fa7cdd6fc9dffa8139f9350f54959b01bf7a1151/src/node_task_queue.cc#L157) and [this test](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/e46c680bf2b211bbd52cf959ca17ee98c7f657f5/test/parallel/test-promise-reject-callback-exception.js). Even `process.stdout.write = process.stderr.write = () => {}` doesn't work to remove those messages.

[EDIT]:
I forgot to mention that I am already handling all the error events for node: `uncaughtException` and `unhandledRejection`. There are additional messages from Node.js only for stack overflows in promises.

With `console.error` you can do something like

```
const origConErr = console.error
console.error = (...args) => {
  if (typeof args[0] !== 'string' || !args[0].starsWith('msg to filter')) {
    return origConErr.apply(console, args)
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work for `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, `Exception in PromiseRejectCallback:`.

Comment: You can "handle" this error in `process.onerror` and `process.onunhandledrejection`

Comment: @Bergi simply not true, I am already handling all the error events in node.js

Comment: [The docs say](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception): "*By default, Node.js handles such exceptions by printing the stack trace to `stderr` and exiting with code 1, overriding any previously set `process.exitCode`. Adding a handler for the `'uncaughtException'` event overrides this default behavior.*" Can you [edit] your question to include your code, please?

Comment: @Bergi as I said, I am already handling `unhandledRejection` among others events and they all work and output only my logging. Only overflows in promise rejection output the additional messages from node.js .

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the link to the nodejs source code, that should've made it clear these are *additional* messages not just the exception itself being printed. And yes, it looks like you cannot turn these off - and I doubt there is a way to fix that, as it seems these only get printed when V8 is in an invalid state, so there is no solution to customise them from javascript code as no javascript code can run at that stage.

Comment: Btw, can you expand on "*I am making a library which handles the overflow*"?

Comment: @Bergi Isn't there a way to customize `stdout` and `stderr` to put the messages through a filter? Like the `console.error` example from above?

[The library](https://github.com/ivangeorgiew/tied-up) is about wrapping functions with try and catch (among other utilities) and when an overflow happens a single error is shown for the function call, instead of many. You can look at `./src/utils/createFunc.js` and then `isFirstCall` and `isNextFirstCall` to see how I do it. (BTW the Readme is outdated)

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the `fprintf` and `PrintCaughtException` that you found do not go through any JS code you could customise.